# Can IPFS files be seen on every computer it is stored on?

Tags: encryption, ipfs

I'd like to develop a Flutter app that will access audio files stored on the IPFS network. I will pin the files to my own storage drive. But does that mean that everyone providing storage space to the network can see my files with their real names IE:myfilename.mp3 or does the file appear with the CID hash name instead of the real name?